# Can a system call be programmatically interrupted?

Tags: c, unit-testing, zeromq, system-calls, interrupt

I am trying to write a unit test for my ZeroMQ application (which I use through the `cppzmq` C++ layer). My problem is that when I try to close my context, it sometimes (seemingly randomly) fails. I don't know why exactly, except that the error code is set to EINTR, meaning an interrupted system call.

To write a (failing) unit test for this behavior (which I can then try to fix), I was thinking ([see also this PR](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/pull/271)) it would be useful if I could somehow spoof these system calls that are getting interrupted. Inside this spoofed system call, I can then first just call the regular system call, but then before returning manually set the error code to EINTR. For instance, I would like to replace [`recv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) with something like:

```
ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags) {
    ssize_t result = ::recv(sockfd, buf, len, flags);
    errno = EINTR;
    return result;
}
```

Is this possible? Is this wise (could I expect problems and if so which)? Is there another way to solve my unit testing problem?

Comment: If you want your `recv` override to always fail with -EINTR, don't make the actual syscall at all. Simply do `{ errno=EINTR; return -1; }`.

Comment: This `::`  looks like C++.

Comment: @PSkocik I should have made more clear that I'm calling the system calls indirectly, through a library which I did not write myself (ZeroMQ).

Comment: @alk I could only use 5 tags. Indeed, as mentioned, I use this library through its C++ interface. I used the C tag here because the POSIX functions are all C.

Comment: I'm now looking into using ptrace from a separate forked process, will report back if this will yield a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Based on this: https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/06/23/

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution is Linux-only. I'm working on macOS (which does not have the PTRACE_SYSCALL option), so not a good option for me.

Answer (score 1):

`EINTR` is returned whenever a properly configured interrupt is received during a blocking system call.

Probably the easiest signal to raise is `SIGALRM`, that can be scheduled by simply calling:

```
alarm(1);
recv(...);
```

And you will get the `SIGALRM` one second afterwards.

If you do not want to wait 1 second, you can get subsecond precision with `setitimer()`.

Comment: This is interesting! Will try. I'm wondering, though: how to get the timing of this interrupt just right in an automated test setup where the system call is called indirectly through another (ZeroMQ) function?

Comment: @egpbos: That would depend on the type of server. You can try setting up a server that somehow does not reply to that request. Since this is a test, you can setup the server in the very same process. A well placed `sleep()` in the server code may do the trick. If you cannot insert a `sleep()` in the correct server point, maybe you can run it in another thread and `SIGSUSPEND` it... Or you can mock the protocol enough to trick the client code into the `recv()` call you want to fail...